# Reset my phone and can't login to whatsapp anymore

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, android-14

I recently reset my phone and tried to install whatsapp again.

I get this [invalid number error](https://faq.whatsapp.com/980349822781515). My number is indeed VOIP but I have been using it for 3+ years but I never faced this problem until today.

I am okay with changing my number to real one, but I need to use the whatsapp change number feature so I don't lose my conversations and people can still find me.

How do I change my number or fix this login issue?

Notes:

1. I use whatsapp web so I am still logged in the web session.
2. I copy media/com.whatsapp before reset. I tried copying it back into my phone after the reset. But it still asks me to login. Maybe there is a way to bypass login if I have the backup?